# If I own a file, why do I need to change permission to write to it?

Tags: command-line, permissions, sudo

If I create a file with `sudo vim test` and then open it up in my account (without `sudo`) why does the editor complain when I try to modify the file (i.e. read only option is set)?

According to `ls -l` I am the owner, and the owner has `rwx`

Why can't I write to the file?

Comment: Are you the owner if you ran the editor under `sudo`? What do `ls -l $file` and `id` show?

Comment: If you created the file with `sudo vim test`, root will be the owner of the file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create a file with `sudo vim test` the owner will be root, not you, so if later you want to edit the file you either need to change the owner from root to you or change the permissions.

See:

```
jordim@bucketlist-196008:~/test$ sudo vim test
jordim@bucketlist-196008:~/test$ ls -l
total 8
(...)
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root      2 Feb 22 15:43 test
(...)
```

The created file belongs to root:root and only root has read and write permissions for it. Rest of the users of the group can only read, as well as any other user from other groups.

The question is, why are you creating the file with "sudo" if you need to edit it later as a regular user?

Answer (score 1):

When you create a file using `sudo command`, the file owner is `root`.

Example:

```
$ sudo vim test
$ ls -lsa test
4 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 5 Feb 22 16:43 test
```

When you are trying to update (write) a file using regular account (which isn't `root`) you won't be able to write to file (unless the file permission will be write-able to everyone)

Example:

```
$ echo "testing 123..." > test
bash: test: Permission denied
```